# Is there a framework for both Android and iPhone development in C#?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, .net

Basically we're looking to develop a relatively simple application, but we only want to do it once. We're a .net development house. As that is our strength, we'd like to stick with that.

I've seen Mono for Android (http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid). Is this good? Does anyone have experience using this for both Android and iPhone?

Comment: You only need to do it properly once, once for iPhone, iPad, Android and WP7 but then it really is done properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) will only allow you to develop Android apps, not iPhone apps. For iPhone apps, consider using [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch). I don't have any experience using these, but keep in mind that they are not free.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a port application from an existing application is not that hard if you know the language. You can rewrite a .Net application easily for Android if you know Java. There is no universal framework however with full native power.

Answer (score 0):

I never try mono On a mobile device,but on the other platform it works not bad.

And there are some apps online now.